Is there the language in the mind and how it changes based on the language in the world?
I have realized that I was thinking in keywords, just like I use on Google, and not in the words itself. So I started to think if there is a "language" that the mind uses to create language that we use in everyday life. And if one can alter the other or be altered through social media, television, search engines, AI/ChatGPT (for me I usually try to make the most easy to understand so that it doesn't give me something wrong), smartphone keyboards (I have to say that I often just write the first letters of the word and choose the one I was thinking) ... how does one do so? What would be the "natural" mind-language? What are the tools/devices that most change our way of using language to be able to use the tools/devices? What other alterations/transformations are you seeing on language in the technological/modern world?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_thought_hypothesis

Chomsky argues that language, to a degree, is inherent in the mind. This is not the specifics of any one language like nouns or verbs, but the notion of a noun and a verb. If I recall correctly, he calls this a deep grammar. He makes this argument after noting that children pick up language without there being enough examlles for them to learn from. This is underlined by large language models which take in toto, all the writing on the net, which is far more than any child, or even a billion children could read in their entire lifetimes.

To decode the language of our mental processes is one of the biggest tasks of neuroscience.
Single neurons communicate with electrical discharge. But the level of the single neuron does not even compare to the level of a single literal. Communication between mental processes happens on the level of neuronal nets which comprise a huge set of neurons firing in a synchronized manner. Signals are electrical waves with a characteristic temporal pattern. I assume that the temporal pattern encodes the content of the message.
A related question about a trained neuronal net seems to me: What is the meaning of the neurons in the intermediate layers?
The Manifest of the neuroscientists from 2004 states:

Auch darüber, mit welchen Codes einzelne oder wenige Nervenzellen
untereinander kommunizieren (wahrscheinlich benutzen sie gleichzeitig
mehrere solcher Codes), existieren allenfalls plausible Vermutungen.
Völlig unbekannt ist zudem, was abläuft, wenn hundert Millionen oder
einige Milliarden Nervenzellen miteinander sprechen.
There are also
at best plausible assumptions about which codes individual or few
nerve cells use to communicate with each other (they probably use
several such codes at the same time). It is also completely unknown
what happens when a hundred million or a few billion nerve cells
talk to each other. (Google translator)

